# How to run WordPress inside public folder of Laravel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I have been searching much more than you think but couldn't find anything useful. Because of this, I'm asking this question.

I want to have WordPress inside public directory of Laravel. I have these configs:

`/public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
    #RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
    # Force http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

`/public/blog/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
DocumentRoot /home/mysite/public_html/public
ProxyPassMatch "^/blog" "unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000/public/blog"
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000/public/index.php"
```

The problem is that `mysite.com` working but `mysite.com/blog` redirects me to `mysite.com` again and `mysite.com/blog/index` returns this page not found that the style is for WordPress.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: This is a bad idea in general, is there a reason you're unable to use a subdomain (e.g: `blog.mysite.com`)? That is the typical approach to solving this problem. At the very least if you must do it this way, you should not put wordpress in the Laravel `public` folder -- you should keep your Wordpress and Laravel installs separate and do the routing at the web server level.

Comment: Only because of SEO and what the team has decided I couln't do that. Could you please tell me how I can do that?